# How to increment and set an id for each node using javascript OOPS concept?

Tags: javascript, oop, raphael

I am creating a Mind Mapping software using raphael.js and javascript.

I want to create a set of nodes where a node is like a rectangle and has its attributes as id, x,y coordinates etc. There is a plus icon on the rectangle on click of which a new node/rectangle is created with its new unique id. I want to create node and assign each created node its id in an Object Oriented fashion.

I am having difficulty in assigning a unique id to each node on its creation. I want to set ids starting from 0,1,2,3...

Second difficulty is selecting a node. I want to select a node based on its id.

Please have a look at the following code.

Could someone please help me in assigning ids to each of the nodes and to select each node based on its id?

```
assume that there is a canvas of 1000px width and 700px height.
       paper = Raphael("canvas", 1000,700);

// create.js

drawNode(290, 80);

function drawNode(x,y)
{
    id=0;
    a =  new node(x,y,id);
    a.drawNode();
}

// nodes.js

var node = function(x,y,id){
    this.id=id; 
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;

    this.drawNode = function(){
        var st = paper.set();
        a = paper.rect(this.x,this.y, 100, 40, 2);
        a.add = paper.image('images/plus.png', this.x+77,  this.y+12, 20, 20)
        a.attr({fill: '#8EDFF0', stroke: '#6AB0F2'});
        st.push(a,a.text,a.add,a.addnote);
        a.add.click(this.add);
    }

    this.add = function () {
        id=1; 
        a =  new node(this.attrs.x+150, this.attrs.y,id);
        a.drawNode();
    }
}
```

Please tell me how can I set unique id to each node instead of hardcoding the values and how to do that.

Comment: Why would you want an id on the nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You, probably, need some `NodeCostructor` singleton with `id` parameter set to 0 from the start and `createNode` as function that accepts x and y, uses `NodeCostructor`'s id to draw a node and returns you a node, than increases `NodeCostructor`'s id value. A basic example of how should it be (**EDIT:** I've found some js singleton tutorial, so this new code will be more valid in terms of OOP):

```
    var NodeConstructor = (function() {
      var instance = null;
      function NCInstanceCreate() {
        var id=0;
        createNode = function(x,y) {
                    tmp = new node(x, y, this.id);
                    this.id++;
                    return tmp;
                }

        return {
          createNode : createNode,
          id : id
        }
      }
      function getInstance() {
        if( ! instance ) {
          instance = new NCInstanceCreate();
        }
        return instance;
      }
      return {
        getInstance : getInstance
      };

    })(window);

    var node = function(x,y,id){
                                this.id=id; 
                                this.x=x;
                                this.y=y; 
            }

    myConstructor=NodeConstructor.getInstance();
    console.log(myConstructor.createNode(100,200));
    console.log(myConstructor.createNode(110,220));
    console.log(myConstructor.createNode(130,240));
    console.log(myConstructor.id);
```

So you basically should use myConstructor.createNode(x,y) instead of new node(x,y,id) whenever you want to create node.